# Flash - Button's Label and Scaling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using a button component in flash and using its label field. When I set the label field to a word, half of it is cut off as my button is too small for the label. Is there any way to adjust the size of the text on the button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Create a TextFormat and then do m_button.setStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat);